# how to send email with .xlsx attachment in sendgrid?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Below is the message object used to send emails.

```
 message = {
        to: toEmail,
        from: emailInfo.emailFromAddress,
        subject: emailInfo.emailSubjectTemplate,
        attachments: [
          {
            filename: fileName,
            content: base64str,
            contentId: fileName,
            disposition: "attachment"
          }
        ],
        html: emailMessageBodyTemplate
      };
```

The content is encoded into a base64 string by the following below code.

```
const base64_encode = file => {
  var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
  return new Buffer(bitmap).toString("base64");
};
```

I don't know where I m going wrong but I'm getting the error as follows.

**message:"The content value must be a string at least one character in length."**

but the content is not empty when I debug it is a base64 string.

Please help.

Comment: did my answer solved your problem ?

Comment: yeah, I just forgot to upvote thanks for the help!!! happy coding;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this [page](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html) it describes exactly your error.

I believe in this error content means your message or a text as error describes

> You may not send an email with no content.

And as per the [API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#body) docs,you are missing a required parameter content.

```
message = {
            to: toEmail,
            from: emailInfo.emailFromAddress,
            subject: emailInfo.emailSubjectTemplate,
            content:[
              {
                 type : 'string',
                 value : 'message'
              }
            ],
            attachments: [
              {
                filename: fileName,
                content: base64str,
                contentId: fileName,
                disposition: "attachment"
              }
            ],
            html: emailMessageBodyTemplate
          };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Broken link to the API

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same issue and in my case I used 'xlsx' npm lib, to implement the solution as follow:

```
const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(data);
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws, 'Accounts');

// write the file in base64 format
const report = XLSX.write(workbook, { type: 'base64', compression: true });

const attachment = {
    content: report,
    filename: `MyReport.xlsx`,
    type: 'text/html',
    disposition: 'attachment'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using `XLSX` but found using base64 format caused issues with the file extension.

[image: Error message in excel]

I found setting the output data encoding to `buffer` solved the issue for me.

```
const content = write(workbook, { type: 'buffer', compression: true });
```